# Using PyQGIS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: pyqgis, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a standalone installation of QGIS 3.10.14 and I would like to use PyQGIS while working in Visual Studio Code.

I have already tried customizing settings file:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\apps\\Python37\\python.exe",
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\python"
],
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
},
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\python"
]
```

I have also tried making several version of .bat file similar to this:

```
@ECHO OFF 
set QGIS_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\

@echo off
call "%QGIS_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%QGIS_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%QGIS_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

cd /d %~dp0

SET VSCBIN=D:\Users\fran\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

call "%VSCBIN%\Code.exe" %*
```

None of these ways were effective since the result is always

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
```

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063439/how-do-i-set-the-pyqgis-environnement-on-windows-properly

Comment: What is QGIS version you use?